# UDP - "ConnectAndSend vs SendTo"

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I am writing code for a simple C# library responsible for managing UDP communication in a client/server architecture.
I based my communication on C# `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient` class, both for the server-side and for the client-side; for the sending feature of the client-side, I saw there are two possible options:

1. perform a single call to `Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint)` to specifiy target endpoint, then perform subsequent calls to `Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes)`, hence without specifying target endpoint
2. always perform calls to `Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes, IPEndPoint endPoint)`, hence specifying target endpoint

regarding first option, if a different target endpoint is required, simply perform a new call to `Connect`.

I've looked at the MSDN, but still a couple of questions remained unanswered:

- **are there any advantages choosing between one option and the other one?** technically the first one seems to me more clean and clear, but the second one gives you this benefit *"If you call the Connect method, any datagrams that arrive from an address other than the specified default will be discarded"*
- **in particular, are there any performance reasons to choose among them?** again, the first one seems to me more optimized.
- **why providing two different ways of achieving almost the same functionality (if not exactly the same)?**

Comment: Option 1 is a Broadcast UDP message.  So search web for broadcast messages.  Your application is a two port application since you are receiving in one connection and sending to another connection.  The second method is not Broadcast and is only one-to-one.

Comment: @jdweng please consider that setting for example XXX.XXX.XXX.255 I am able to broadcast even with option #2; so I would say the distinction is not based on broadcasting capability

Comment: IP 255 can be the broadcast IP for a subnet depending on the protocols implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slight differences between the two approaches I was able to find are:

1. `Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint)` with `Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes)` restricts the client to send data exclusively to the end point it is connected to and implies *any datagrams that arrive from an address other than the specified default will be discarded*.
2. `Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes, IPEndPoint endPoint)` allows to send data to different end point at each call, without need to perform a reconnection.